# Proof that if and g are continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f =\int_a^bg $ then $\exists \, c \in [a,b] : f(c) = g(c)$.

Tags: calculus, integration

If f and g are continuous on $[a,b]$ and $\int_a^b f =\int_a^bg $ then $\exists \, c \in [a,b] : f(c) = g(c)$.

I am struggling with proving this formally (although it's pretty intuitive).
I've seen other proofs on this forum but they all have the initial condition that $f(a)>g(a)$ and $f(b)<g(b)$.

Answer (score 4):

$F(x)=\int_a^x(f-g)(t)dt$, $F(a)=F(b)=0$, apply rolle.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, any Idea without using Rolle? I understand it but we didn't talk about it in class, so I guess there must be another way.

Answer (score 2):

A possible argument without using Rolle theorem is this:

Assume for all $x\in[a,b]$, $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)\neq 0$. By continuity, we must have $h>0$ or $h<0$ on $[a,b]$. (otherwise, by intermediate value theoerem we conclude there is some $x$, s.t. $h(x)=0$ which contradicts our assumption about $h$).

Assume, w.l.o.g, $h>0$ on $[a,b]$. Then we deduce $\int_a^b h(x)dx>0$. This implies $\int_a^b f(x)dx\neq\int_a^b g(x)dx$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the [first mean value theorem for integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals) to the function $h=f-g$.

$h$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, according to the theorem there exists $c \in (a,b)$ such that:

$(b-a)h(c) = \int_a^b{h} = \int_a^b{f}-\int_a^b{g} = 0$

This implies that $\exists c \in [a, b] : \quad h(c) = f(c)-g(c) = 0$